# .net core web api. How should my route allow for optional parameters when the last one just needs to be set

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core

I've got the following request from my employer and I was wondering if you could give me a suggestion.

For simplicity here is an example of what I have for the following get student controller

I've created a GET route with the following parameters api/students/{LcID}/{AffiliateId}/{StartDate?}/{EndDate?}/{Email?}

The StartDate, EndDate, and Email are optional parameters. Everything works fine with this setup but my employer wants to know
if the client can just send the LcId, AffiliateId, and Email. Can that be done?

I've tried using Postman to set the name and value parameters LcID=1/AffiliateId=123/Email=myemail@email.com but that didn't work.

Should I change my parameters into an object that needs to be passed in? I don't really want the user to have to fill in the other fields with dummy values in-between the parameters that do get filled in. I hope this makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you use api routing, you can not use that type of query. I want to know your routing structure. Can it be changed like this.  `[Route("{LcID}/{AffiliateId}/{Email?}")]`

Comment: @MarioSalento,If my answer is helpful to you ,you can mark it as answer,thank you very much!

Comment: Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to know how to mark

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `Route` to your `Action`, like the following:

```
 [HttpGet("LcID={LcID}/AffiliateId={AffiliateId}/{StartDate?}/{EndDate?}/{Email?}")]
 [HttpGet("LcID={LcID}/AffiliateId={AffiliateId}/Email={Email}")]
```

Then in your Postman:
[image]

If there are other requirements, you can continue to add them.

Comment: If my answer is useful to you, please don’t forget to approve it as an answer, thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you!  You put me in the right track to solving this issue.